# PHP array with hours avaliable not marking correct date

Tags: php, arrays

I'm creating a simple system to display a calendar with the hours that are avaliable for appointments. To do that I'm using 3 informations:

- List of the days of week;
- List of the hours that can be scheduled;
- List of day/hours that have already been taken on that week;

However, when I run the code If I have 08:00h already taken on monday, it's marking all the other days as taken as well.

This is my code:

```php
$list_hours = array(
  (object)array(
    'hour' => '08:00',
    'avaliable' => 1,
  ),
  (object)array(
    'hour' => '09:00',
    'avaliable' => 1,
  ),
  (object)array(
    'hour' => '10:00',
    'avaliable' => 1,
  ),
  (object)array(
    'hour' => '11:00',
    'avaliable' => 1,
  ),
  (object)array(
    'hour' => '12:00',
    'avaliable' => 1,
  ),
);


$list_avaliable = array(
  array(
    'day' => 2,
    'hour' => '09:00',
  ),
  array(
    'day' => 4,
    'hour' => '10:00',
  ),
);


$lista_days = array(
  'Sun',
  'Mon',
  'Tue',
  'Wed',
  'Thu',
  'Fri',
  'Sat',
);

$new_list_hours = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
  $item = new \StdClass();
  $item->name = $lista_days[$i];
  $item->hours = $list_hours;

  foreach ($list_avaliable as $avList) {
    if ((int)$avList['day'] === $i) {
      foreach ($item->hours as $ihList) {
        if ($ihList->hour === $avList['hour']) {
          $ihList->avaliable = 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  array_push($new_list_hours, $item);
  unset($item);
}

print_r($new_list_hours);
```

The problem is that, if I run this code, for every week day the hours 09:00 and 10:00 will be set to `avaliable: 0` when I want this to happen only on the days Tuesday and Thursday.

This is the code online to test: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0b932b30a2554f2b448ceb7eed1ae19c8acd92e1

Comment: The core of your issue lies in references. Objects are passed/assigned by reference. You have an array of objects in `$list_hours`. Later you assign this array to an object property: `$item->hours = $list_hours;`. After that, you change a property in the loop (where `$ihList` is one of the objects from the array): `$ihList->avaliable = 0;`. At this point, the object in your original array `$list_hours` is changed, because you're working with a reference to it, not a copy. So every further assignment `$item->hours = $list_hours;` is made with those hours already marked as unavailable.

Comment: @El_Vanja I imagined that this was the problem. But I have 2 questions. If the $list_hours starts with all `avaliable = 1` and the first date to check is 2 (tuesday), why sunday and monday also have the `avaliable = 0`? Second, how to solve this issue, any ideas?

Comment: All days reflect the change because all days reference the exact same object. It doesn't matter which day changed it, they will all ultimately see the same property. The easiest fix is not to initialize the array beforehand, but rather put the definition inside the assignment: `$item->hours = [ ...your whole array... ]`. That way you get fresh instances in each iteration.

Comment: @El_Vanja I understood. The problem is that `$list_hours` (and `$list_avaliable` as well) is a set of data that comes from the database. So if I assign each time inside the loop, I would need to to make a request everytime.

Comment: In that case, the next easiest fix I can propose is that you do the whole process with pure arrays and only cast to objects once you're done.